# Where I'm wrong when importing From Arduino sketch into Atmel Studio 7, (about DHT11)

Tags: hardware, atmega328p

Atmega 328p is tested on a breadboard with LCD1602 and DHT11. I am programming this with SNAP MPLAB via Atmel Studio. On Arduino Uno everything is fine, but on the breadboard, DHT11 not responding. This is the code:

[image]

```
/*Beginning of Auto generated code by Atmel studio */
#define F_CPU 8000000UL
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <Arduino.h>

/*End of auto generated code by Atmel studio */

#include <dht11.h>
//#include <Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
//Beginning of Auto generated function prototypes by Atmel Studio
//End of Auto generated function prototypes by Atmel Studio


//int stare = 0;
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x3F, 20, 4); // set the LCD address to 0x27 for a 16 chars and 2 line display
dht11 DHT;
#define dhtpin A1                   //pinout 24

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  //lcd.init();                      // initialize the lcd
  lcd.init();
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.backlight();

  //  digitalWrite(15, HIGH);
  digitalRead(dhtpin);

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  int d = DHT.read(dhtpin);
  //delay(500);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  //lcd.print(d);
  lcd.print("Temp = ");
  lcd.print(DHT.temperature);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("Humidity = ");
  lcd.print(DHT.humidity);
  delay(1000);
 }
```

Comment: Can you upload the sketch from Arduinos IDE?

Comment: Yes, I can upload the sketch on Arduino Uno and working. Atmega 328P on the breadboard is another CI with internal oscillator (8MHz). I want to fully program in Atmel Studio and sometimes to use library from Arduino. I do not think it is from internal clock because sensor DHT11 is in long time responding (~1s).

Comment: Does the stand alone 328 have a bootloader installed, if yes, which one? What good does **digitalRead(dhtpin);** do? Are you running the breadboard version on 5 V?

Comment: The pullup resistor on the DHT11 data line seems to be missing.

Comment: Exist 10K in capsule sensor. And the same sensor on Arduino Uno is working without adding resistor.

Comment: Have you connected the sensor to power and ground? In your picture I can see the connections